# How to monitor redis clusters

Tags: redis, monitoring, redis-cluster

I can monitor single redis instance through [redis-stats](https://github.com/junegunn/redis-stat) but if I want to monitor a redis cluster, I need to specify each server name. But if I add more servers to cluster, then I need to add more servers to redis-stats. So is there any utility so that I can monitor all servers in a cluster.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Data-Dog or new-Relic for monitoring each redis-node and then you can create proper dashboard as well.